# Repeatedly blocked from SSH server due to failed login attempts

Tags: mac, ssh

I use a Mac (running Mojave) to login to my university's HPC, using iTerm. When I login from home, I almost always get blocked, because apparently my IP gets blacklisted due to hundreds of repeated failed login attempts. This doesn't happen when I login from the on-campus library or off-campus university research center.
I am puzzled by what is causing all these login attempts, when all I do is open iTerm and try to SSH.
Any clue what I should be looking for?
Thanks!

Comment: It is likely they have whitelisted those locations. You would need to configure your client to limit the amount of simultaneous connections.